# Actualizar campos simultaneos con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

quisiera ver la manera de actualizar varios campos a la vez, solo estoy mandando un datos que es un status (si o no) con el respectivo Id a actualizar este es el codigo que tengo pero me surge un problema.

```
<?php
    $conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','overtime');

    $InpIdOt=$_POST['InpIdOt'];
    $Status=$_POST['AprobOt'];

    foreach (array_keys($_POST['AprobOt']) as $key) {
        $InpIdOt = $_POST['InpIdOt'];
        $Status = $_POST['AprobOt'];

        $update = 'UPDATE overtime.registros SET status= "'.$Status.'"
                WHERE id="'.$InpIdOt.'"';
    
    echo mysqli_query($conexion,$update);
    }

?>
```

Me esta mostrando el siguiente error:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Overtime\src\UpdateApOt.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Overtime\src\UpdateApOt.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />
1<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Overtime\src\UpdateApOt.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Overtime\src\UpdateApOt.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />
1<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Overtime\src\UpdateApOt.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Overtime\src\UpdateApOt.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />
```

Y de esta forma mando mis inputs:

```
<td style="display: none;"><input type="text" name="InpIdOt[]" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="AprobOt[]" value="si">Aprobado</td>
```

Comment: Si haces un `var_dump` de `$InpIdOt=$_POST['InpIdOt'];` ¿Qué obtienes?

Comment: Lo imprimi fuera del foreach y me dio esto: string(2) "47"

Comment: Ya vi por que, no le estaba poniendo al input el name="InpidOt[]" el problema es que ahora me da este error al enviar <b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Overtime\src\UpdateApOt.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />

Comment: Por qué haces esto? `echo mysqli_query($conexion,$update);`, es decir por qué intentas imprimir ahí?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que menciona el error del OP:

> Array to string conversion

Se produce en esta línea:

```
echo mysqli_query($conexion,$update);
```

Esto sucede, por que no podemos hacer un ´echo´ directo a la función ´mysqli_query´. Para poder leer estos datos, debemos hacer ´var_dump()´ o var_export():

```
var_dump(mysqli_query($conexion,$update));
```

Ahora, referente a la "solución" del OP, esta difiere demasiado en los errores que el menciona. Por lo que no se puede tomar como la solución al error.

Answer (score -1):

La solucion fue la siguiente:

Me faltaba agregar la parte [$key] en el ciclo foreach

Quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach (array_keys($_POST['AprobOt']) as $key) {
        $InpIdOt = $_POST['InpIdOt'][$key];
        $Status = $_POST['AprobOt'][$key];

        $update = 'UPDATE overtime.registros SET status= "'.$Status.'"
                WHERE id="'.$InpIdOt.'"';
    
        mysqli_query($conexion,$update);
}
```

Comment: Bueno sería eso y por lo que muestras quitar el `echo` ¿no?

Comment: Esa no es la solucion al problema de la pregunta.

Comment: Si quitar el echo, y pues eso me soluciono el problema por que no me dejaba registrar mas que el ultimo dato ya con el Key me deja actualizar segun el id que yo mande.